# How to check pf's queues?

Tags: freebsd, queue, pf

I use FreeBSD and working with pf+ALTQ now.
Something doesn't work and I need a tool to view what requests are marked and moved to a queue "queue_name"
Need something like pftop but showing queues. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `pfctl -s queue -v` or `pfctl -s queue -v -v` for continuous output.

Comment: Interesting thing is that man-page doesn't contain this view. All others but not this one!

Comment: ok. :) please click the question answered.

Comment: Strange indeed. NetBSD manual says "-s queue Show the currently loaded queue rules. ..."

Comment: can be answered only after 10mins.

Comment: Also `pftop -s1 -v queue` can be used to watch traffic speed and byte counters